# Scss transition property not working after Svelte transition

Tags: javascript, sass, svelte, scss-mixins, svelte-transition

I have an element that have a transition in with svelte. But in my css I have a transition property that doesn't work right after the svelte transition is finished.

My element with the in transition :

```
<div
      in:scale={{
        delay: 250,
        duration: 650,
        easing: quadInOut,
      }}
    >
      <img
        src="https://picsum.photos/200"
        alt="mobile version"
      />
    </div>
```

and here is the scss code where there is the problem

```
> div {
      transition: transform 0.75s ease; //transform transition that doesn't trigger

      @media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
        @for $i from 1 to 5 {
          &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
            @include global.offset(random(750) + px, 0); //translating each elements with transform property
          }
        }
      }
```

So my element snap to its translating place right after the svelte transition which is bad, but it doesn't go slowly there.

Comment: This sounds like it could have something to do with margin or padding. Is it possible that something gets applied after the transition ended?

Comment: The elements have no padding and the only margin that is applied is a ```margin-bottom```

Comment: Did you try removing or increasing it to see if that makes a change?

Comment: Yes I completly removed it and it didn't change anything. I also tried ```transition: all``` but no difference

Comment: I made a REPL, that surprisingly works but I don't see what's different than my code. Maybe SCSS instead of CSS but it will be strange. https://svelte.dev/repl/9432bca953e74d9f95259a7ec9a6abef?version=3.56.0

Comment: Don't know about the SCSS, but maybe rendering the elements with an #each loop and setting the transform translate on them directly could be an alternative? https://svelte.dev/repl/857d8842388048d083836f964690d08c?version=3.56.0

Comment: Yes that's perfect. I added an each loop and added the pictures with a store and it works fine. Thanks a lot !